# .max() for dataframe converts object type to float64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have 3 columns namely

```
   "A",         "B"
 -7.480000e+01,-1.480000e+01
-7.410000e+01,-1.410000e+01
-7.370000e+01,-1.370000e+01
-7.360000e+01,-1.360000e+01
-7.370000e+01,-1.370000e+01
-7.390000e+01,-1.390000e+01
```

Whenever I do `df[["A","B"]].max(axis=1)`, it ends up giving a float value. Something like
Output:

```
   "C"     
 7.12
9.12
1.1231
6.1231
1.123
8.421
```

I wanted

```
       "C"     
  -7.480000e+01,
    -7.410000e+01
    -7.370000e+01,
    -7.360000e+01,
    -7.370000e+01
    -7.390000e+01
```

Tried using `.astype(str)` but no luck.

Comment: How is max of -7.480000e+01,-1.480000e+01 -> 7.12? 7.12, 9.12, 1.1231..where did they come from?

Comment: @Ch3steR it's just an example. The values are just dummy values

Comment: You want output in scientific notation?

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df.apply(lambda x: '{:e}'.format(max(x['A'], x['B'])), axis=1)
```

If values of 'A' and 'B' are strings:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: '{:e}'.format(max(float(x['A']), float(x['B']))), axis=1)
```

Comment: Gives an error saying `Unknown format code 'e' for object of type str, occured at index 0`

Comment: Looks like values in 'A' and 'B' are strings.

Comment: And you want to use max() operator on strings? If not, convert columns A and B to float.

Comment: Yeah I changed how I was reading the csv into the dataframe into float.